# How can I make a radio button go to another HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to do something like, when I click the radio button it goes to another HTML.

my code:

```html
<div class="FilterNetwork">
  <div class="network">
    <input type="radio" value="Expertise" unchecked name="radioBtn" onclick="expertise.html"> <label> Expertise</label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="Location" unchecked name="radioBtn"> <label> Location</label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="Workplace" unchecked name="radioBtn"> <label> Workplace </label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="Past Job" unchecked name="radioBtn"> <label>Past Job</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need a radio button to perform this?

Comment: you want the radio button to redirect the user to expertise.html? Why not just make it a regular button? Either way, inside onclick, you need `window.location = "expertise.html"`

Comment: `onclick="window.location='expertise.html'"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a javascript class that does something like:

```
<div class="FilterNetwork">
  <div class="network">
    <input type="radio" value="Expertise" unchecked name="radioBtn" onclick="dosomething(Expertise)"> <label> Expertise</label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="Location" unchecked name="radioBtn" onclick="dosomething(Location)"> <label> Location</label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="Workplace" unchecked name="radioBtn" onclick="dosomething(Workplace)"> <label> Workplace </label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="Past Job" unchecked name="radioBtn" onclick="dosomething(PastJob)"> <label>Past Job</label><br>
  </div>
</div>

<SCRIPT>
function DoSomething(foo) {
if (foo = 'Expertise') {
window.location.replace("expertise.html");
}
else if (...) {}
else if (...) {}
else if (...) {}
}
</SCRIPT>
```

This also could allow you to pass a variable inside of () that specifies different actions for each button. Cheers

Comment: can I do something like this, if I wanted to check their expertise? onclick='checkexpertise(".$row['JOB_NAME'].")'

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the onclick attribute, example onclick="location.href='example.html'".